# pushing my git repo with newly added .gitignore entries seems to write a lot more objects than it should

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clean up one of my repos so committing is much easier, I've decided on a few folders to ignore to drop the size of my repo from ~100mb to ~6mb.

I've git rm --cached -r . and git add . then git commit -m "commit" but when I git push origin master it compresses the same number of objects as before, and says writing objects: x% (X/12954) which, 12000+, is much higher than the actual number of objects? So I'm a bit confused.

I hope this screenshot helps explain it a little more
https://gyazo.com/39e1d6710f30f32e34d73c85a1f37481

Thanks for any feedback or help

Comment: Once something is in a commit, it is always there in the history (unless you re-write history).

Comment: the objects folder seems to be stuck at ~750mb

Comment: @crashmstr Ahh okay, is it an acceptable solution to clear/rewrite the history?

Comment: Generally, you don't want to modify history for anything shared with others (i.e once pushed).

Comment: @lopu It depends. How many People are working on this repo? How many cloned from it? Rewriting means you mess with all of them

Comment: It's just me lol, but isn't this a common occurence when you've forgotten to ignore directories such as node_modules or public/img from the get go and it adds like 1gb, then you have to refactor the whole repo? Or do people usually config correctly from the git go?

Comment: It's certainly a good approach to start as you mean to go on. Configure a basic .gitignore from the start and then pay attention to what `git status` tells you as you go along. It's usually easy to spot things that shouldn't be included in the repo.

Comment: Ahh so maybe I should reinit the repo?

Comment: Please see my answer. If you re-initialise the repo you'll lose all your history. It is possible to retain it while removing the files you no longer wish to have been added to the repo.

Comment: I just reinited, don't particularly need the history

Comment: @lopu Some take-away thoughts: try to remember your `.gitignore` at the beginning, but also look at each commit beforehand and look at what you will be committing (avoid blindly doing `git add .`!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing your files at this point is too late as they already exist in the history of the repo. You would need to remove these files from the history.

You can use the following command to remove files from your git history.

**However please be aware:** this command will re-write your git history. Please work on a copy of your repo and not the original until you're entirely happy.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch [paths]' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

`[paths]` could be a single path like `myfolder/unwantedfile.txt` or it could be multiple paths separated with spaces like `myfolder/unwantedfile.txt myfolder/anotherfile.txt anotherfolder/oldfile.txt`.

If you are not sure of the paths of the files you can use the below command.

```
git rev-list --objects --all | sort -k 2 | cut -f 2 -d\  | uniq
```

This will list every file that has ever been committed to your repo.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this, I simply rm -rf .git and re git init and made a new repo on github. Wouldn't you agree it's a tiny bit of a flaw that simple file names of deleted folder contents can bloat a repo commit by 50 fold? Your rewrite history does the trick but I don't see why it should affect other's so badly. I guess my use case, a website with an overly large img directory is the least of the examples this would be detrimental in

Comment: No problem :). It will only affect others who have already checked out your repo as the history will change wherever a file was removed. If it's just you working on it then it wouldn't have been a problem :).

Comment: @lopu: this is *not a bug*. The point of commits is to save your work *forever*. If you don't want a 50 MB set of files saved forever, *don't commit them*. Git does have these various tools to alter saved history, in case you made a mistake and saved things you should not have, but if you have distributed the saved history elsewhere, remember that you now must get everyone *else* who has that saved history to take your revised history.